# what is the solution of the given differential equation which is generated by applying the lagranges equation on the graph xy=c

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How could I solve this  ode ?

$$({x^5}+{c^2}{x}) \frac{d^2 x}{d t^2}-\ 2{c^2}\Bigl(\frac{dx}{dt}\Bigr)^2-gc{x^3}=0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an autonomous second-order differential equation, so we can write it as a  first-order equation in $x$ and $v = dx/dt$:
$$ {\frac {dv}{dx}}  ={\frac {2\,{c}^{2}  v^{2}+gc{x}^{3}}{ \left( {x}^{5}+{c}^{2}x \right) v }}
$$
That is a Bernoulli differential equation.  The change of variables $v = \pm\sqrt{u}$ transforms it to a linear differential equation
$${\frac {d}{dx}}u \left( x \right) =4\,{\frac {{c}^{2}u \left( x
 \right) }{x \left( {x}^{4}+{c}^{2} \right) }}+2\,{\frac {gc{x}^{2}}{{
x}^{4}+{c}^{2}}}
$$
whose general solution is
$$ u \left( x \right) =-{\frac {2gc{x}^{3}}{{x}^{4}+{c}^{2}}}+A {\frac {{
x}^{4}}{{x}^{4}+{c}^{2}}}
$$
where $A$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: How could I solve  v ????
the value of v is being ridiculous to solve the equation.

Comment: You'll get implicit solutions involving an integral that can't be done in closed form.  If you're looking for an explicit closed-form formula for $x(t)$, I'm afraid you're not going to find one.